# Знак после «Что, если» в начале фразы

Tags: многоточие, вопросительный-знак, двоеточие-тире

***«Что, если(.../?)»(:) (—) самые безумные сценарии, которые невозможно представить.***

В первой скобке указано, поставить «?» или «...». Какой лучше?

А после кавычек, интересно, поставить двоеточие или тире?

«Что, если(.../?)», думаю, что значит, объяснять не нужно.

Comment: Там же один сценарий, а не несколько.